# shutil samefile error on Linux

Tags: python, python-2.7, shutil

I have a python script that is giving me a hard time on Ubuntu 12.02 with Python 2.7.3.

PS: it runs without problems on Windows.

```
>>> import os
>>> import shutil

>>> shutil.copy("/mnt/my_network_dive/somewhere/sample.xml", "/mnt/my_network_drive/COMPLETED/")
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 117, in copy
        copyfile(src, dst)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 69, in copyfile
        raise Error("`%s` and `%s` are the same file" % (src, dst))
shutil.Error:    `/mnt/my_network_dive/somewhere/sample.xml` and `/mnt/my_network_drive/COMPLETED/sample.xml` are the same file
```

Checking some properties of the files:

```
>>> os.path.exists("/mnt/my_network_drive/somewhere/sample.xml")
True
>>> os.path.exists("/mnt/my_network_drive/COMPLETED/sample.xml")
True
>>> os.stat("/mnt/my_network_drive/somewhere/sample.xml")
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33272, st_ino=4913809333, st_dev=25L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=0, st_size=5447, st_atime=1465311674, st_mtime=1465311674, st_ctime=1465311685)
>>> os.stat("/mnt/my_network_drive/COMPLETED/sample.xml")
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33272, st_ino=4913809333, st_dev=25L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=0, st_size=10, st_atime=1465317482, st_mtime=1465317482, st_ctime=1465317483)
>>> os.path.islink("/mnt/my_network_drive/somewhere/sample.xml")
False
>>> os.path.islink("/mnt/my_network_drive/COMPLETED/sample.xml")
False

>>> shutil._samefile("/mnt/my_network_dive/somewhere/sample.xml", "/mnt/my_network_drive/COMPLETED/sample.xml")
False
```

As you see, calling `shutil._samefile` I get `False` but `shutil.copy` still raise the `samefile error`.

Am I forgetting something? Any other way to move or copy files with Python?

Comment: There's no need to copy them. They're two different directory entries pointing at the same file. Being the same file, there's no possible way their contents can differ.

Comment: (Why `shutil._samefile` returns False is a different question, and perhaps something to file a bug over, but since `st_dev` and `st_ino` are identical, there's no question that it genuinely is the same content pointed to by both directory entries).

Comment: @vmenezes The first argument of copy in the first box contains dive instread of drive, is it only typo?

Comment: On Macintosh & Unix `shutil._samefile()` uses `os.path.samefile(src, dst)` which is only available on those platforms to determine if two paths are the same. On other platforms like Windows, it just compares the two normalized absolute path strings — which is likely part of why the results differ.

Comment: What type of mount is my_network_drive? NFS, CIFS or ??

Comment: it is a CIFS @tdelaney

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the two files are both hard links to the same file.  You can tell because they share the same inode number

```
st_ino=4913809333
```

Windows users generally don't create hard links.  They are more common in linux environments, which is why you may have not encountered the problem until now.

It is odd that `samefile` returns `False`.  What OS are you using?  `shutil._samefile` is just a wrapper around `os.path.samefile` (on systems where that function exists).  What results do you get from `os.path.samefile`?  On posix systems, it just checks that the device and inode match (which they do in your case) and it should return `True`

*posixpath.py*

```
def samefile(f1, f2):
    s1 = os.stat(f1)
    s2 = os.stat(f2)
    return samestat(s1, s2)

def samestat(s1, s2):
    return s1.st_ino == s2.st_ino and s1.st_dev == s2.st_dev
```

Comment: It's likely that one or both of the parent directories are symlinks to the same directory.

Comment: @tdelaney But `samefile` should still return `True` in that case, right?

Comment: Yes, I am as puzzled by that as you. As with a hard link, the dev and inode should be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the exnplanation @BrendanAbel I'm using Ubuntu 12.02

I ended up doing a `os.system("cp --remove-destination file1 file2")` to workaround it.

Comment: getting worse, there is another app that probably doesn't use context management well and sometimes it creates a new file on my `dest_folder` but dont save it and quit. When I try to copy from `src_folder` to `dest_folder` on another script with `shutil` I get the same errror, but if I go on shell `ls -la dest_folder` the folder is empty.
Sounds crazy and probably I could blame the other script but `os.system("cp --remove-destination src_file destfile")` worked.

Answer (score 0):

In **python 3** in shutil.copy there's additional argument follow_symlinks=True
Look at this https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html

> If follow_symlinks is false, and src is a symbolic link, dst will be created as a symbolic link. If follow_symlinks is true and src is a symbolic link, dst will be a copy of the file src refers to.

Comment: Doesn't answer OP's question about Python 2.7.3.

Comment: @martineau But maybe checking how it works in Python 3 could help determine if that's the problem. If yes, maybe he could look at the source of the newer version and copy this code.

Comment: How do you know it's not a problem with using Python 3 as well?

Comment: @martineau Dear Martin, I don't insist that it would solve the whole problem, but probably it has do with links. I only recommend to check both options for follow_symlink in Python 3. If with one of them it works properly we can always import this solution to Python 2.7 - we can always copy code and redefine this function. I suggested this transition to Python 3 and its version of shutil solely to diagnose the problem and presumable solution. Quote "How do you know it's not a problem with using Python 3 as well?" - I don't know because we don't have access to his network drive.

Comment: the problem was bigger then that, there was actually times that even when the dest_file didn't exist I was getting the same error(because another script using the file before crashed without closing the file, I could get out of python and run `ls -la` in the folder and there was no file in there but when copying it would break with `same file` error).My workaround was `os.system("cp --remove-destination src_file dest_file")`.

Comment: vmenezes: Glad you found a work-around...but it sounds like you still don't know what causes the problem when you try to use Python.